# Error while installing hashicorp/aws: permission denied

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terraform

I downloaded the latest version of terraform into my amazon linux server and I put it under **/opt/terraform/1.6.3** directory. I named this latest version: terraform163, then I created a symlink to the new version under /opt/terraform:

```
ln -s  /opt/terraform/1.6.3/terraform terraform163
```

This is the content of the path /opt/terraform:

```
drwxrwsr-x  10 ec2-user terraform 241 Nov 15 12:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root     root      122 Dec  1  2022 ..
drwxr-sr-x   2 ssm-user terraform  23 Jul 27  2021 0.12.23
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Nov 25  2021 0.13.7
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Nov 25  2021 0.14.11
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Nov 25  2021 0.15.5
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Nov 25  2021 1.0.11
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Dec 23  2021 1.1.2
drwxrwsr-x   2 user     terraform  23 Nov 15 12:41 1.6.3
drwxrwsr-x+  4 user     terraform  54 Dec 20  2021 plugin_cache
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     terraform  30 Dec 23  2021 terraform -> /opt/terraform/1.1.2/terraform
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ssm-user terraform  32 Jul 27  2021 terraform.12 -> /opt/terraform/0.12.23/terraform
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     terraform  31 Nov 25  2021 terraform.13 -> /opt/terraform/0.13.7/terraform
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     terraform  32 Nov 25  2021 terraform.14 -> /opt/terraform/0.14.11/terraform
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     terraform  31 Nov 25  2021 terraform.15 -> /opt/terraform/0.15.5/terraform
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     terraform  30 Nov 15 12:41 terraform163 -> /opt/terraform/1.6.3/terraform
[user@ip-10-193-192-5 terraform]$ pwd
/opt/terraform
```

Now when I make a `terraform init` using this new version I get this error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/template from the dependency lock file
- Installing hashicorp/aws v5.25.0...
- Installing hashicorp/template v2.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/template v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/aws v5.25.0: mkdir
│ /opt/terraform/plugin_cache/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/5.25.0/linux_386:
│ permission denied
╵

ERRO[0010] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

What did I miss ?
Thank you

Comment: Well, permissions to perform write actions in the said directory are missing.